# How is EC2 instance utilization computed?

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, amazon

I'm currently on free tier but I'm thinking about moving into a t2.small instance to be able to do more. At this point, I'm just really interested in having some personal tools on the cloud (something that I could have done if I had spare machine that I can set up as a home server), so I'd like the cost to be very minimal. I checked the AWS calculator, and it wants me to estimate the utilization, but I don't really understand how it is computed. If your EC2 instance runs 24/7, does that mean it has 100% utilization even if it only does significant work for maybe some hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilization in EC2 for cost purposes means the number of hours in a month that the instance is up and running, compared to the number of hours in a month.

The workload is not a factor in price.

Instances in the t2 class also have a concept of "CPU Credits," because t2 machines are burstable.  They earn credits at a fixed rate while running,  spend credits at a rate that varies with CPU utilization, and can only use 100% CPU when there are sufficient credits on hand (1 credit = 1 core used at 100% for 1 minute, or 1 core used at only 10% for 10 minutes, etc.), but this also is not a factor in cost.  The credits are included with the instance, and the charge is the same whether they are used or not.  There is no way to purchase more credits, and the performance of the instance does not vary unless the balance is depleted, and will recover in its own whenever the instance is idle.

Comment: So that means if I have an instance up 24/7 for the entire month, it's 100% utilization? Is there a way to schedule when they start and stop automatically?

Comment: There are ways to start/stop on schedules and in response to monitored conditions, but this can also have the opposite effect if done in a cavalier fashion -- a machine stopped and started every 30 minutes is actually 200% utilization.  A start event bills you for the one hour minimum, even if you stop it almost immediately, which is not unreasonable.  Two "start" events per hour would then result in a monthly cost double that of a machine left alone.  This is not a secret, it's documented, but there are a lot of docs to familiarize yourself with.